# Precompile with not updatable view causes not been pre-compiled exception

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure

So I created a brand new MVC 4 project for intranet in VS 2013. I did not do any modification to the project and published it to Azure with the following settings:
- Remove additional files at destination
- Precompile during publishing -> unchecked Allow precompiled site to be updatable
- Exclude files from the App_Data folder

And then when I browse to the site I got "The file '/Views/Home/Index.cshtml' has not been pre-compiled, and cannot be requested."

Note that if I leave Allow precompiled site to be updatable checked then I got no problem at all. Is this feature broken or something??

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem when I had a third party dll installed into GAC (Global Assembly Cache). The publish did not copy the dll to the ouput bin. 
The exception was a bit missleading and it occured only on those pages that referenced the dll (controls in the markup). It did work with allow updatable checked.

Now I have removed the external dll from the GAC and I have no problems with any publish settings.

Comment: i did not install any third party dll, this is happening on a brand new created project

Answer (score 0):

Repeat this process few more time if not succeed.

1. Re-publish Code one more time.
2. Before copy any files to destination, delete only **root/bin** folder.
3. Copy only **bin** folder from your local to destination folder.

   > > Copying other files to destination will be west of time if you did already.